# How you are or How are you?

Tags: questions

In English Question format is

Question world (Wh- , How) + Auxiliary + subject + Object?

a) How are you feeling now?

b) How you are feeling now?

Which one is correct to ask in above Question?

Answer (score 1):

The **first** version is a correct question. The other word order is used for reported speech (no question mark):

> *Tell me* how you are feeling now.